# HMR not working in Vite with Flow and .js files using JSX loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite, vitest

I am currently migrating my React project from Create React App (CRA) to Vite. In my project, I use Flow for type-checking, and my file extensions are .js. I have set up Vite with the Flow plugin and the JSX loader for .js files. However, I am facing an issue where HMR (Hot Module Replacement) is not working as expected, and the page is being reloaded every time I make a change.

Here is my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from "vite";
import { flowPlugin, esbuildFlowPlugin } from "@bunchtogether/vite-plugin-flow";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import viteCompression from "vite-plugin-compression";
import path, { extname } from "path";
import fs from "fs";
import { createRequire } from "module";
import { getConfig } from "./config/feature";
import checker from "vite-plugin-checker";
import Inspect from "vite-plugin-inspect";
// import { manualChunksPlugin } from "vite-plugin-webpackchunkname";
// import { chunkSplitPlugin } from "vite-plugin-chunk-split";


const buildConfig = {
    outDir: "dist",
    assetsDir: "client/app/js",
    manifest: true,
    minify: true,
    reportCompressedSize: true,
    cssCodeSplit: true,
    sourcemap: true,
    commonjsOptions: {
        transformMixedEsModules: true,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
        output: {
            interop: "esModule",
            esModule: "true",
            sourcemap: true,
            entryFileNames: "static/js/bundle.js", // If you need a specific file name, comment out
            chunkFileNames: "static/js/[name].chunk.js", // these lines and uncomment the bottom ones
            assetFileNames: (assetInfo) => {
                const info = assetInfo.name.split(".");
                const extType = info[info.length - 1];
                if (/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|webp|webm|mp3)$/.test(assetInfo.name)) {
                    return `media/[name]-[hash].${extType}`;
                }
                if (/\.(css|scss)$/.test(assetInfo.name)) {
                    return `css/[name]-[hash].${extType}`;
                }
                if (/\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/.test(assetInfo.name)) {
                    return `fonts/[name]-[hash].${extType}`;
                }
                return `[name]-[hash].${extType}`;
            },
        },
    },
};

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode, isSsrBuild, isPreview }) => {
    if (command === "serve") {
        console.log(`Server is started on  https://local.xyz.com:8081/`);
        return {
            base: "/",
            server: {
                cors: true,
                open: true,
                https: {
                    key: fs.readFileSync("./local.xyz-key.pem"),
                    cert: fs.readFileSync("./local.xyz.pem"),
                },
                host: "local.xyz.com",
                port: 8081,
            },

            preview: {
                cors: true,
                open: true,
                https: {
                    key: fs.readFileSync("./xyz-key.pem"),
                    cert: fs.readFileSync("./xyz.pem"),
                },
                host: "local.xyz.com",
                port: 8081,
            },
            logLevel: "error",
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    routes: path.resolve(__dirname, "client/app/js/routes_out.js"),
                    "~@ag-grid-community": path.resolve(__dirname, "node_modules/@ag-grid-community"),
                },
            },
            esbuild: {
                loader: "tsx"
                include: [
                    "client/**/*.tsx",
                    "client/**/*.ts",
                    "client/**/*.js",
                ],
                exclude: [],
            },
            // Add below line once we move to typescript
            // checker({ typescript: true })
            plugins: [react(), Inspect(), flowPlugin()],
            optimizeDeps: {
                esbuildOptions: {
                    plugins: [
                        esbuildFlowPlugin(
                            /\.(flow|jsx?)$/,
                            (path) => {
                                if ([".js"].includes(extname(path))) {
                                    return "tsx";
                                }
                            },
                            { all: false, pretty: true, ignoreUninitializedFields: false }
                        ),
                    ],
                },
                loader: {
                    js: "tsx",
                },
            },
        };
    }
});
```

I am using the latest version of Vite. The project runs without issues, but HMR is not working for .js files. It do works for .tsx files.

Additional Information:

tried

> vite --debug hmr

only the changed file is logged but the page is getting reloaded.